# Python appending 2D array?

Tags: python, maya

it has been a while for me doing python scripting after about 8 months of hiatus. Really need some insights.
I have been trying to set or modify the camera filmback/film gate attribute via coding and after much trial and errors, I finally found the command for it but now I am meeting with some other issues..

The first item in list, in Python terms - the index usually starts from 0, however in Maya term's for this filmbackMenu, it starts from 1.

```
cmds.optionMenu('filmbackMenu', edit = True, select = 0) # Errors-out, stating that it is out of range
cmds.optionMenu('filmbackMenu', edit = True, select = 1) # No errors
```

Suppose if my filmback Menu is as follows:

```
list01 = ['itemA-01', 'itemB-02', 'itemC-02', 'itemD-01', 'itemE-01', 'itemF-03']
list01.insert(0,"")
for index, item in enumerate(list01):
    print index, item
```

while I manage to find a way to have my items start from index '1' by inserting a dummy/blank.. 
As I am trying to filter out anything that contains '-01' and append both the name and the index into list02, however I only know how to do for either just the name or the index, but I believe I will need both. This is my code section:

```
list02 = []
for i in list01:
    if '-01' in str(i):
        list02.append(i)
# Result: ['itemA-01', 'itemD-01', 'itemE-01']  # The index here should be 1, 4, 5
```

Is it possible to append both the name and the index together? For example, itemA-01 1, 'itemD-01' 4 , 'itemE-01' 5?
The index need not be shown in the UI, the name will do, still I will need to grab the index value eventually...

Kindly see below for my code, perhaps that may give a better insight and please do feel free to criticize if need be.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

list01 = ['itemA-01', 'itemB-02', 'itemC-02', 'itemD-01', 'itemE-01', 'itemF-03']
list01.insert(0,"")
for index, item in enumerate(list01):
    print index, item

list02 = []
for i in list01:
    if '01' in str(i):
        list02.append(i)

window = cmds.window()
cmds.columnLayout()
cmds.optionMenu (label = 'Select a format')
for x in list02:
    cmds.menuItem(label=x)
cmds.button( label = 'Ok')
cmds.button( label = 'Cancel')

cmds.showWindow( window )
```

What happens in my UI is that, upon the user selection, eg. if I selected itemD-01 which is of index 4, the following code should run:

```
cmds.optionMenu('filmbackMenu', edit = True, select = 4)
```

Notice that the flag for select will be changed..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add a dummy element to your list enumerate has a second argument that indicates the position it should start from. using this you can store the index and the item side by side in a separate list

```
list02 = []

list01 = ['itemA-01', 'itemB-02', 'itemC-02', 'itemD-01', 'itemE-01', 'itemF-03']
for index, item in enumerate(list01, 1):
    if '-01' in item:
        list02.append([index, item])

print(list02)
```

result

```
[[1, 'itemA-01'], [4, 'itemD-01'], [5, 'itemE-01']]
```

You can even turn in into an elegant list comprehension

```
result = [[index, item] for index, item in enumerate(list01, 1) if '-01' in item]
```

Comment: cool, didn't know that I can enumerate it in this way... Was wondering if you may have any ideas as to how I can return the value in the `command` flag in the `cmds.button`? When I tried something like `print item`, it keeps printing the last item in the list02..

Comment: something like this `cmds.optionMenu('filmbackMenu', edit = True, select = list02[0])`?...i'm not familiar with maya or you mean return the value when the user clicks on a button

Comment: I am doing something simple like `cmds.button( label = 'Ok', command = ('print list02[0]'))` but in actual fact, I am trying to capture/return the index value based on the selection. The UI will be in a function - eg. `def ui()` in which the whole execution will takes places in another function..